# PayPal - paying without paypal's account is not returning to my store

Tags: paypal

PayPal - paying without paypal's account is not returning to my store when complete.

> Abdula ben Sulejman, you just completed your payment. Your receipt
>   number for this payment is: 0000-0000-0000-0000.
>
> We'll send a confirmation email to z_**_**_ya@gmail.com. This
>   transaction will appear on your statement as PayPal *ILYAIZSTEST.

I dont recieve any email from paypal. So how to check that payment?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you asked how to check the payment details, but was not sure if you were curious as to how to return the customer from PayPal back to your store/website. which is what your title seems to imply.

**There are 2 ways of returning the customer to your store.**

1. In your PayPal account, you may enable [Auto Return](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside). After the customer has confirmed their payment with PayPal, Paypal will automatically re-direct the customer to your specified `return_url`. In order to send transaction information to your `return_url` as well, take a look at enabling [Payment Data Transfer (PDT)](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer).
2. In your button code, you may specify the `return_url` as a `hidden` input variable. Once the customer has confirmed their payment with PayPal, PayPal will direct the customer to PayPal's receipt page. On this page, PayPal will provide the link you specified.

An example of a *Buy Now* button, may look like this:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Teddy Bear">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">

<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="http:/example.com/success" />

<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

For further research, [read more here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_buynow_buttons#id089UI0M0IL7).

As far as checking the payment from the buyer's end, the buyer would either have to wait for the transaction to appear on their statement as specified by PayPal, or should contact the seller for transaction details.

Comment: "Paypal will automatically re-direct the customer to your specified return_url" This won't be automatically done for any unregistered buyers. They'll need to click an orange "Return to merchant" button before they're redirected.